# How to handle all errors Pycord

Tags: error-handling, discord.py, pycord

I am trying to find a way to handle all errors in Pycord.
After that error is caughtit should send it to the user who caused the error.
How would I do this?

A quick example of what I've done.

```py
@client.event
async def on_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    if isinstance(error, discord.commands.errors):
        await ctx.send("Unknown command")
```

Answer (score 0):

`discord.commands.errors` doesn't seem to be a class. Try either [`discord.ext.commands.CommandError`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandError) or [`discord.DiscordException`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.DiscordException) as a catch instead of `discord.commands.errors`. Or you could drop the isinstance and resend the error no matter what.

Comment: Also, if you explicitly want to catch command not found errors use `discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound`

Comment: And also add an `else: raise error` or something similar or else all other errors will not be shown