# How can I import a cog into my main.py file?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

My cog file isn't sending any errors but does not work. A friend of mine suggested importing the cog to my main file. I previously checked on Stackoverflow on how to import it but the method along the line of `import (file name here, without extension)` doesn't exactly work. I am using the Pycord library by the way.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity = discord.Game("Being Handy."))
  print("Bot is ready!")

## - Cog Loader --------------------------------------------------

cogs = ["cogs.Secondary"]

Start_Decor="----- Connecting Cogs -----\n---------------------------"
End_Decor = "\n---------------------------\n----- Cogs  Connected -----"
Fail = "N/A"
Success = False

for cog in cogs:
  try:
    client.load_extension(cog)
    Success = True
  except Exception as e:
    if Fail == "N/A":
      Fail = f' Failed to connect the following:\n\n{cog}: {str(e)}'
    else:
      Fail += f'\n{cog}: {str(e)}'
if Success == True and Fail == "N/A":
  print(f'{Start_Decor}\n✅ Connecting Cogs\n{End_Decor}')
elif Success == True and not Fail == "N/A":
  print(f'{Start_Decor}\n✅ Connecting Cogs\n\n{Fail}\n{End_Decor}')
else:
  print(f"{Start_Decor}\n{Fail}\n{End_Decor}")

@client.slash_command()
async def main_test(ctx):
  await ctx.respond("Working", ephemeral = False)

## - Code Below --------------------------------------------------

client.run(os.environ.get("BOT_TOKEN"))
```

^^^ My Main file.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime


class Secondary(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    
    self.client = client

  @commands.slash_command()
  async def cog_test(self, ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Working.", ephemeral = False)
      
def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Secondary(client))
```

^^^ My cog file.

Comment: discord catches all errors and hide them to work stable all time. You may need to use `logging` to change setting and display errors. And importing file is not enough. Did you do `bot.add_cog(YourCog(bot))`? You have to inform `bot` that it has to use this `cog`. You didn't show code so we have no idea what is the real problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @furas I'm not sure if that's [the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72997136/what-errors-does-discord-py-hide-by-default). Anyhow, this is pycord, not discord.py

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and elaborate on what doesn't work. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: If you don't get error about importing then it imports correctly. But import doesn't means it will know what to do with this `cog`. It still may need to run your `imported_file.setup(clietn)` in `main.py`. But we have no idea what you are doing in `main.py`.

Comment: And you could try to use `logging` in your code - even if it is not `discord`. OR you could search in documentation information about debugging. BTW: using Google I found also [discord.py - How to handle all errors Pycord - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197390/how-to-handle-all-errors-pycord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import your cog into your discord bot, you have to use the `bot.load_extension()` method which takes the file in parameter:

At the end of your main file:

```
my_files = ["YOUR FILES HERE WITHOUT EXTENSION"]
#For example, if my files are cog1.py and cog2.py and is located in the cogs folder:
my_files = ["cog1", "cog2"]

for file in my_files:
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file}")
```

Don't forget to put the setup function in your cog file

See https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.Bot.load_extension

Comment: I've already done this. The cog itself loaded successfully, no errors show in output but yet still nothing in the cog works. None of the commands work nor do the slash commands show up on Discord.

Comment: Can you show a your main.py's code and you cog's bot please ?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit my post.

Comment: In your cog file, there is a function named `cog_test` However, no commands can start with cog. You should then rename your function `test`. I tried changing that and it's now working. In the future, please include the error you get, in this case "commands can't start with `cog_`...

Comment: Thanks, changing the name of the function worked but the thing is, I never got an error.